# Failing compilation if return value is unused for a certain type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to make compilation fail for some function call but not others. The function call that I want to fail are those that do not handle return values when the value is of a certain type. In the example below, not handling a function returning `Error` is a compilation error but not handling a function that returns anything else should succeed just fine.

Note: our runtime environment (embedded) does not allow us to use the following constructs: RTTI, exceptions.

This code only needs to compiler with Clang, I would prefer not having to annotate each function.

We prefer a solution that fails at compile time instead of at runtime.

```
enum class Error {
  INVAL,
  NOERR,
};

// do something that can fail.
Error DoThing();
// may return different return codes, we never care (we can't change prototype)
int DoIgnoredThing();

int main() {
  DoThing(); // compilation failure here, unused "Error" result
  DoIgnoredThing(); // compilation succeeds, OK to ignore unused "int" result
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall`, clang should warn you about all unused values I believe and then just make warning into errors with `-Werror`.

Comment: Jesse, this will not be a sufficient solution because the example above will emit a diagnostic for `DoIgnoredThing`

Comment: @JesseGood: Does it complain of unused *values* or unused *variables*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I was mistaken, `-Wall` enables `-Wunused-variable` and `-Wunused-value`, but to get what the OP wants you need to use Tom Pannings answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to do it with straight C++, but if you're using g++ you can use the [warn_unused_result attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) along with the -Werror=unused-result command-line flag. See the documentation for warn_unused result for how to specify it (you'll have to specify it on every function unfortunately; I don't believe you can specify it for a type). Then the compiler flag will turn that warning into an error.

If you're not using g++, your compiler may have similar functionality.

Comment: Actually, the code will still compile with non-gcc compilers (http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) but you'll only get the benefits if you use gcc (or a compiler that understands this gcc attribute).

Comment: @JonathanSeng: I find it interesting that you don't see this as a solution considering your answer. That is, if in your answer you replace *code analysis tool* with `g++ -Werror=unused-result` you are proposing exactly the same thing.

Comment: I suggest a tool that works cross platform without using platform specific solutions (and probably finds more bugs by using a tool designed to find bugs).  Also, I am merely stating the fact of not being portable, not down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use a code analysis tool to scan the source code.

This might let you use the return type, as you requested, or a different marker for the functions to test like a comment to indicate which functions should be checked.

You might run the analysis tool as part of the compilation process or as part of a build server.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few ways to make a class that would do what you want, but I haven't been successful. Have you considered making your "return value" an argument passed by reference? That's the most common way that I've seen APIs force you to pay attention to the return value. So instead of

```
Error DoThing();
```

you have

```
void DoThing(Error& e);
```

Anything that calls DoThing() has to pass in an Error object or they will get a compiler error. Again, not exactly what you asked for, but maybe good enough?