# Forcing a call to a class operator== to fail if return value is unused on GCC 4.4.7

Tags: c++, gcc

I would like to know if there is a way to turn the use of a `operator==` on a class into a compiler error if the result is doing nothing with the result. The reason is to catch a use of the `operator==` when instead the developer intends to use `operator=`.

I do not care if the solution is GCC specific, as long as it works on GCC 4.4.7. Solutions can include GCC-specific attributes, compiler pragmas, or a source code file changes on the C++ class given below.  Less attractive are changes to compiler options.

See example below. Uncomment the `#define DO_STRING_LITERAL_TEST` line below and you will see a helpful message from the compiler:

```
/usr/bin/g++  -MD -DDEBUG -g -ggdb -gstabs+ -O0  -fPIC  -Wall -Werror -Wsynth -Wno-comment -Wreturn-type   main.cpp -c -o main.o
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**, char* const*)’:
main.cpp:37: error: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour
```

Comment the `#define DO_STRING_LITERAL_TEST` line, but then uncomment the `#define DO_STRING_CONTAINER_TEST` line. This compiles just fine and I would like it to fail on the line indicated:

```cpp
foo == " "; // <-- I need this to throw a compiler error
```

Here is the example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class StringContainer {
private:
  std::string _val;

public:
  StringContainer(const char * inString = NULL) : _val(inString ? inString : "") {}

  bool operator==(const StringContainer & other) const
  {
    return _val == other._val;
  }

  void operator=(const char * other)
  {
    _val = other;
  }

  const char * getString() const
  {
    return _val.c_str();
  }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *const envp[])
{
  std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << "main begin" << std::endl;

#define DO_STRING_LITERAL_TEST
#ifdef DO_STRING_LITERAL_TEST
  const char * invalidval = "foo bar";
  // The following use of == throws a nice compiler error on GCC 4.4.7:
  invalidval == " ";
#endif // DO_STRING_LITERAL_TEST


//#define DO_STRING_CONTAINER_TEST
#ifdef DO_STRING_CONTAINER_TEST
  StringContainer foo;
  foo = "some string";
  foo == " "; // <-- I need this to throw a compiler error
  std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << "foo contains <" << foo.getString() << ">" << std::endl;
#endif // DO_STRING_CONTAINER_TEST


  std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << "main end" << std::endl;
  return 0;
} // end main
```

One answer came very close is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12416677/257924 . But that specifies use of a function attribute, which looks quite attractive, however the version of the GCC compiler that I am required to use balks at the use of `-Werror=unused-result`:

```
cc1plus: error: -Werror=unused-result: No option -Wunused-result
```

If there was a source-code-only change that temporarily (for some segment of code, perhaps) the `unused-result` warning, that would be even better. https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-6850#commentauthor_55299_verbose apparently indicates that "same test with gcc 4.8.3 passes ok, since it supports the param."

Comment: You get this for free by comparing constants first: `1 = var` is a compile-time error

Comment: I doubt this is possible as the function has no way to know if its return value is used.  Also would you consider `if(foo == " ")` an error?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez The OP wants the use of `==` to be an error if the return is not assigned to something.

Comment: You could return an object whose destructor asserts if `operator bool` is not called on it.

Comment: This wish is misconstrued. If your developers use `==` instead of `=`, you need to hire new developers.

Comment: @Nathan Ah, I see.  I suppose you could create some class that wraps the bool and throws if the value isn't extracted?

Comment: isnt the opposite a much more common mistake, i.e. to use `=` when it should be `==` ? Actually I dont remember that I ever saw a `==` when it should be `=`

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Maybe but that IMHO would be horrible if you need to use the comparison.

Comment: Couldn't you upgrade the compiler version ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Upgrading the compiler version is the only option I see so far from reading the comments. And we will eventually. But I wanted to see if there was a quicker solution that doesn't require such a sea-change in the compilation tool chain.

Comment: @Nathan I am looking for a compile-time error check.  Throwing an exception would be caught at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be something you verify in code. This should be something that your compiler will do for you. If you need a `std::string`, you should use a `std::string` - not a `MyStringThatHasThisExtraEqualityCheck`.

I'd suggest one of several things:

- Bug your favorite gcc developer to get them to implement `-Wunused-comparison` as per [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62182)
- Just compile your code with clang, which does support that warning. You can then add `-Werror` to make it an error. You don't need to run the clang binary, but an extra orthogonal couldn't hurt (just gives you more excuse to [slack off](https://xkcd.com/303/)).
- Use some external static analysis tool to verify this stuff for you.
- Write unit tests.

Comment: I agree with you. However, the wrapping of the `std::string` is just for this example just to show what I need to catch at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

GCC allows the `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` on a function.  Have you tried it with your class's comparator?

**EDIT:** Never mind.  Skipped over the section where you say that your old GCC version still does not support that attribute.

Comment: The attribute may be supported but the `-Werror=unused-result` command line option gives an error.